# Get localized core data strings list on runtime?

Tags: localization, ios4

I know i can generate a .strings file with "genstrings" in terminal.
In my case many of the strings are coming from core data and they are not literally written on xcode.

is there a way to generate the list of the strings on runtime?

Thanks
Shani